# Search for a substring between special character in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a string like

```
(&(objectclass=${abc})(uid=${xyz}))
```

How can I search **${abc}** and **${xyz}** and replace with another strings. There can be **any number of occurence** of such substrings i.e.${abc} in main string. I was thinking of `string.indexOf(` but that could be messy. Any best approach?

${abc} will be replaced by another string abc. I will get them from some other parameters.

Comment: And you want to replace with what? Do you have some sort of map for replacements?

Comment: replace with simple strings. ${abc} will be replaced by another string abc

Comment: Yes, but where do you get these strings from?

Comment: from some parameter. They can be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `String.indexOf(String sep, int start)` in a loop repeatedly to copy text and values to a StringBuilder.

---

Something like

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("abc", "ABC");
    map.put("xyz", "XYZ");
    printSubstitue("nothing to change", map);
    printSubstitue("(&(objectclass=${abc})(uid=${xyz})(cn=${cn})(special='${'))", map);
}

private static void printSubstitue(String text, Map<String, String> map) {
    String text2 = subtitue(text, map);
    System.out.println("substitue( "+text+", "+map+" ) = "+text2);
}

public static String subtitue(String template, Map<String, String> map) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int prev = 0;
    for (int start, end; (start = template.indexOf("${", prev)) > 0; prev = end + 1) {
        sb.append(template.substring(prev, start));
        end = template.indexOf('}', start + 2);
        if (end < 0) {
            prev = start;
            break;
        }
        String key = template.substring(start + 2, end);
        String value = map.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            sb.append(template.substring(start, end + 1));
        } else {
            sb.append(value);
        }

    }
    sb.append(template.substring(prev));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

prints

```
substitue( nothing to change, {abc=ABC, xyz=XYZ} ) = nothing to change
substitue( (&(objectclass=${abc})(uid=${xyz})(cn=${cn})(special='${')), {abc=ABC, xyz=XYZ} ) 
     = (&(objectclass=ABC)(uid=XYZ)(cn=${cn})(special='${'))
```

---

It gets messy if you want to support nested `${ }` values. ;)

```
abc123=ghi123
abc${xyz}=def${xyz}

(&(objectclass=${abc${xyz}})(uid=${xyz}))
```

I would suggest you keep it simple if you can. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters (`$` , `{` , `}` ). Try this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\$\\{abc\\}","abc");
```

---

This can be weird but can help you out:

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("${")+2, str.indexOf("}"))
```

This will work for all (any number of) strings between `${` and `}`.

Comment: How can I know its abc. It can be "abcdef"

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is `\$\{[^}]+\}`. Replace with whatever is necessary.

edit: OK, I misunderstood the question. Regex fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A regex like this works:

```
String regex = "(\\$\\{YOUR_TOKEN_HERE\\})";
```

Here is an example of usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] lines = {
        "(&(objectclass=${abc})(uid=${xyz}))",
        "(&(objectclass=${abc})(uid=${xyz})(xyz=${xyz})(abc=${abc}))"
    };

    String token = "abc"; // or whatever

    String regex = String.format("(\\$\\{%s\\})", token);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    for (String s: lines) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.err.println(m.replaceAll("###"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output for token = "abc" is:

```
(&(objectclass=###)(uid=${xyz}))
(&(objectclass=###)(uid=${xyz})(xyz=${xyz})(abc=###))
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I know that its abc and xyz? It can be abcd or asdfgsdf